# Why __GFP_HIGHMEM flag can't be applied to the __get_free_page() or kmalloc()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to know basically the two things

1. How does the kmalloc works i mean which function kmalloc calls to allocate memory is it alloc_pages() or __ger_free_pages().
2. Why Why __GFP_HIGHMEM flag can't be applied to the __get_free_page() or kmalloc()

I got the folowing extract from the LKD Robert Love can any body better explain that what is exact probelm with the alloc_pages() while giving __GFP_HIGHMEM flag.

Page # 240 CHAPTER 12

> You cannot specify __GFP_HIGHMEM to either __get_free_pages() or
>   kmalloc(). Because these both return a logical address, and not a page
>   structure, it is possible that these functions would allocate memory
>   not currently mapped in the kernel’s virtual address space and, thus,
>   does not have a logical address. Only alloc_pages() can allocate high
>   memory.The majority of your allocations, however, will not specify a
>   zone modifier because ZONE_NORMAL is sufficient.

Comment: And what is wrong with LKD explanation?

Comment: My exact query is why we need pointer to page to allocate memory from _GEP_HIGHMEM region .

Why we can't do it with the system call returning the logical address.

Comment: __ger_free_pages returns pointer to mapped page, it don't perform mapping, That is why it can only return address from lowmem, not from highmem. Cuz page from highmem may be not mapped in current VA space.

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the book Linux Device Drivers 3rd edition (freely available [here](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)), *"the Linux kernel knows about a minimum of three memory zones: DMA-capable memory, normal memory, and high memory"*. The `__GFP_HIGHMEM` flag indicates that *"the allocated memory may be located in high memory"*. This flag has a platform-dependent role, although its usage is valid on all platforms.

Now, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory), *"high Memory is the part of physical memory in a computer which is not directly mapped by the page tables of its operating system kernel"*. This zone of memory is not mapped in the kernel's virtual address space, and this prevents the kernel from being capable of directly referring it. Unfortunately, the memory used for kernel-mode data structures must be direct-mapped in the kernel, and therefore cannot be in the HIGHMEM zone.

Comment: MY question is regarding the paragraph why we can't use __GFP_HIGHMEM in malloc. exact reason.

Comment: but slab is using alloc_pages to get pages, and kmalloc is based on slab, so why can't kmalloc use __GFP_HIGHMEM?

Comment: kmalloc can use GFP_HIGHUSER flag(https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kmalloc.html),  GFP_HIGHUSER includes __GFP_HIGHMEM.